# Rails: Jquery issue with connecting to voting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I just successfully created a voting system and I would like to make one button do both the voting up and down instead of two buttons. I am trying to work my way around the js file for this but I still see two buttons, any suggestions? Thank you.

**Micropost Controller**

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController 
  def vote_up
    @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:id])
    current_user.vote_exclusively_for(@micropost)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to :back }
      format.js
      end
  end

   def unvote
    @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:id])
    current_user.vote_exclusively_against(@micropost)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to :back }
      format.js
      end
  end
end
```

**JS Files**

*vote_up.js*

```
$("#<%=micropost.id%>").html('<%= "#{micropost.votes_for}" %>');
$(".<%=micropost.id%>").html('<a href="/microposts/<%= micropost.id%>/unvote" data-remote="true" class="SquekCounterButton b2 <%= micropost.id%>"><span class="SquekCounterIcon <%= micropost.id%>"></span></a>');
```

*unvote.js*

```
$("#<%=micropost.id%>").html('<%= "#{micropost.votes_for}" %>');
$(".<%=micropost.id%>").html('<a href="/microposts/<%= micropost.id%>/vote_up" data-remote="true" class="CounterButton b2 <%= micropost.id%>"><span class="CounterIcon <%= micropost.id%>"></span></a>');
```

**Micropost HTML**

```
<div class='Counter'>
<span class='CounterNum'><span id='<%= micropost.id%>'><%=micropost.votes_for %></span></span>
<div class='<%=micropost.id %>'>
<a href="/microposts/<%=micropost.id %>/vote_up" data-remote='true' class='CounterButton b2'>
<span class='CounterIcon'></span>
</a>
</div>
<div class='<%=micropost.id %>'>
<a href="/microposts/<%=micropost.id %>/unvote" data-remote='true'class='CounterButton b2'>
<span class='CounterIcon'></span>
</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A different approach:

Create only one action, "toggle_vote" instead "vote_up", "vote_down". First call to "toggle_vote" will "vote_up", second call "vote_down", etc..

"vote_toggle.js.erb" should update button status depending on vote status.

Comment: How would you go about coding that, if it isn't too much to ask can you show me an example?

Comment: In your model Micropost, define a method to know if a user has voted up or against.

In your action, use that method to call vote_exclusively_for or vote_exclusively_against. 

In your view (js.erb), use again the new method yo get the vote status and update the button HTML code with the correct one.