# Rails: Format JS not being picked up by data-remote

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

The JS is not being picked up by the data-remote of each link. I am trying to create one button that does voting and unvoting, like the old digg.com voting button. At this time because the JS is not being picked up I have two buttons each separate for voting and unvoting and I would like to combine the two. I am unsure why the JS is not being picked up. Any suggestions? Thank you.

**Micropost Controller**

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController 
  def vote_up
    @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:id])
    current_user.vote_exclusively_for(@micropost)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to :back }
      format.js
      end
  end

   def unvote
    @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:id])
    current_user.vote_exclusively_against(@micropost)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to :back }
      format.js
      end
  end
end
```

**JS Files**

*vote_up.js*

```
$("#<%=@micropost.id%>").html('<%="#{@micropost.votes_for}"%>');
$("#vote-<%=@micropost.id%>").html('<a href="/microposts/<%=@micropost.id%>/unvote" data-remote="true" class="CounterButton b2 <%=@micropost.id%>"></a>');
```

*unvote.js*

```
$("#<%=@micropost.id%>").html('<%="#{@micropost.votes_for}"%>');
$("#unvote-<%=@micropost.id%>").html('<a href="/microposts/<%=@micropost.id%>/vote_up" data-remote="true" class="CounterButton b2 <%=@micropost.id%>"><span class="CounterIcon <%=@micropost.id%>"></span></a>');
```

**Micropost HTML**

```
<div class='Counter'>
<span class='CounterNum'><span id='<%= micropost.id%>'><%=micropost.votes_for %></span></span>
<div id='vote-<%=micropost.id %>'>
<a href="/microposts/<%=micropost.id %>/vote_up" data-remote='true' class='CounterButton b2'>
<span class='CounterIcon'></span>
</a>
</div>
<div id='unvote-<%=micropost.id %>'>
<a href="/microposts/<%=micropost.id %>/unvote" data-remote='true'class='CounterButton b2'>
<span class='CounterIcon'></span>
</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about the errors you're seeing?

Comment: @James There isn't a specific error that comes up, it is just that the remote-data of the vote links are not picking up on the JS and I am confused to as why the JS is not being picked up. Because the JS is not being picked up I have two buttons next to each other rather than two buttons switching on and off when it is clicked.

Comment: What does the log show when you click on one of the buttons?

Comment: @James Not entirely sure what you are looking for but it shows that the vote has been submitted and stored in the db but there is no sign of the js file coming up, is there something I am missing that is not connecting them?

Comment: Is it processing the get request as html or js?

Comment: @James This is what shows after Get....`Processing by MicropostsController#vote_up as HTML`

Comment: What javascript files are being included in your pages?

Comment: @James Am I suppose to add those js files in the assets/javascript folder? Because I was told to put those js files in the micropost folder in views

Comment: No, I need the list of javascript files (in order) that are being included on that page. If it's processing it as html and not js then that means that the unobtrusive javascript file probably isn't being loaded.

Comment: `<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "modal" %> 
<%= javascript_include_tag "basic_js" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "http://www.google.com/jsapi"%>`

These are the only js files on the header of that specific page, how would I add those js files into that page, mmm shouldn't the js files for voting be in the same folder as micropost and be fetched from that folder?

Comment: What version of Rails are you using? You're missing the unobtrusive javascript file, which would either be `rails.js` or `jquery_ujs.js`. That's why `data-remote` isn't doing anything.

Comment: @James I am using rails 3.2.0 and ruby 1.9.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try combining all your calls to `javascript_include_tag` into a single call and also include `jquery_ujs`:

`javascript_include_tag :jquery, :jquery_ujs, :modal, :basic_js, 'http://www.google.com/jsapi`

Although since you're on Rails 3.2, you should really be taking advantage of the asset pipeline which you can read more about here:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Your `application.js` would then look something like this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

And then you would simply do:

`javascript_include_tag :application`

But try the other method first.

Comment: I did `javascript_include_tag :application` all the js files show but the thing is why do I still have two buttons, doesn't that mean the js files that are in the micropost folder is not being fetched by the link?

Comment: It is fetching the JS nvm but hmm can you help with why I still have two buttons rather than one just switching back and forth?

Comment: Is the get request still processing as html in the log?

Comment: Nope it is getting as JS thank you for this, but the issue is why am I getting two buttons side by side rather than one?

Comment: ...Because you wrote html for two buttons/links. One of them links to the *vote_up* action and the other one links to the *unvote* action. I'm not sure what you're trying to ask.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, mmm better way to say it is how can I go about making one button do both those actions rather than two? I appreciate your help so much. Thank you :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9419430/603420 except `vote_toggle.js.erb` would be named `toggle_vote.js.erb` if your action was named `toggle_vote`.

Comment: I thought it could be done just by those two JS, anyways thank you so much James :)